# Replace multiple chars with multiple chars in string

Tags: kotlin, replace, replaceall

I am looking for a possibility to replace multiple different characters with corresponding different characters in Kotlin.

As an example I look for a similar function as this one in PHP:

```
str_replace(["ā", "ē", "ī", "ō", "ū"], ["a","e","i","o","u"], word)
```

In Kotlin right now I am just calling 5 times the same function (for every single vocal) like this:

```
var newWord = word.replace("ā", "a")
newWord = word.replace("ē", "e")
newWord = word.replace("ī", "i")
newWord = word.replace("ō", "o")
newWord = word.replace("ū", "u")
```

Which of course might not be the best option, if I have to do this with a list of words and not just one word. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can maintain the character mapping and replace required characters by iterating over each character in the `word`.

```
val map = mapOf('ā' to 'a', 'ē' to 'e' ......)
val newword = word.map { map.getOrDefault(it, it) }.joinToString("")
```

If you want to do it for multiple words, you can create an extension function for better readability

```
fun String.replaceChars(replacement: Map<Char, Char>) =
   map { replacement.getOrDefault(it, it) }.joinToString("")


val map = mapOf('ā' to 'a', 'ē' to 'e', .....)
val newword = word.replaceChars(map)
```

Comment: Note that for API versions below 24, ```map.getOrDefault``` has to be replaced with ```map[it] ?: it```

Answer (score 3):

Just adding another way using `zip` with `transform` function

```
val l1 = listOf("ā", "ē", "ī", "ō", "ū")
val l2 = listOf("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")

l1.zip(l2) { a, b ->  word = word.replace(a, b) }
```

`l1.zip(l2)` will build `List<Pair<String,String>>` which is:

```
[(ā, a), (ē, e), (ī, i), (ō, o), (ū, u)]
```

And the `transform` function `{ a, b ->  word = word.replace(a, b) }` will give you access to each item at each list `(l1 ->a , l2->b)`.